# How to extend Illuminate\Routing\Route in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want extend Illuminate\Routing\Route and use it in this way:

```
request()->someCustomFunction();
```

any suggests ?

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own class that extends `Illuminate\Routing\Route` and the n in your service provider you can bind it like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\Route', 'YourClassThanExtendsRoute');
 }
```

This should works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is more a hack since Laravel 5 where it became more difficult to extend the default router. All you need is to add the following into your `bootstrap` file.

```
$app->singleton('router', \App\Services\Router::class);
```

Your new router stored in `App/Services/Router.php` will look like:

```
namespace App\Services;

class Router extends \Illuminate\Routing\Router
{
    public function someCustomFunction() {
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
Router::someCustomFunction();
```

This solution was discussed in Laravel forums [here](https://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2015-l5-extending-router)