# How to inject a custom property to Illuminate Routing Route class

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.4

In other words, how could I override this class to add custom property to the Route class. For instance suppose the following in `routes/web.php`:

`Route::get('/post', 'PostController@index')->description('This is the posts list')`

The above code will generate undefined method error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::description()`

I have tried define it in the `providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` as the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public $description = null;

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()....

     .....

    public function description($txt = null)
    {
        $this->description = $txt;
    }
}
```

Also the same undefined method error is coming.

I tried the answer of [How to extend Illuminate\Routing\Route in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915619/how-to-extend-illuminate-routing-route-in-laravel) as the following:

```
//in AppServeiceProvider.php
public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
            $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
        }
         $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\Route', \App\Http\Helpers\FoxRoute::class);
    }
```

The above solution seems to be not feel with `FoxRoute` even before defining it at app\Http\Helpers there is no any error generated while the undefined method error is exist the following is the `FoxRoute` class:

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Helpers;
class FoxRoute extends Illuminate\Routing\Route
{
    public function __construct($methods, $uri, $action) {
        parent::__construct($methods, $uri, $action);
    }
}
```

I want to define such a method and make it return a property for description in the route object like defaults() !

Comment: `description` should be defined in `FoxRoute`, not in the provider.

Comment: @AlexBlex Although after defining a public method name `description`  in FoxRoute it returns the same error. However, as I regarded, Laravel does not seem to get any interaction with FoxRoute using the way that I have introduced it in srerviceproviders!

Comment: IMHO I think you have to extend the `Router` class not the `Route`, the same for binding